brew services mysql get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error" - MySQL quit without updating PID file
Suddenly after restarting the machine, I have been facing this error can't connect to MySQL server and table plus is not able to connect with localhost 127.0.0.1.
I have tried to run the mysql.server start it's giving me quit without updating PID file.
I have tried to login with terminal
mysql -u root

It's also throwing
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
I have tried to login with terminal
mysql -u root

It's also throwing
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
I have tried by reinstalling the mysql server but still facing the same error.

The steps below worked for me, and can probably work for you, too! However, you will need to install HomeBrew if you don’t have it already.
brew doctor
brew remove mysql

Above remove mysql will not remove databases, So you can easily run the above commands.
brew install mysql

Once you installed the latest version of mysql then try to see the folder of mysql installation by running
which mysql

It should show like this one "/opt/homebrew/bin/mysql".
The final step should be writable permissions for the mysql var folder by running.
chmod -R 0777 /opt/homebrew/var/mysql

It's dangerous be careful for running the permission command or you can just try to find the exact config file and then provide the permission according to it.
This has resolved socket and PID error for me.

I have tried and its working fine, thanks for sharing.
